# Kill background service from different app

Tags: android, android-service

I have two separate applications, the first one has a background service (STICKY) that runs continuously, and in the second application I would like to kill that service, so it gets restarted.
I tried with `killBackgroundProcesses()`, but it didn't work (I added permission to the manifest).
Can I even kill the service from a different app, and if yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

If you have Root and Superuser try use this code:

```
ActivityManager activityManager = ((ActivityManager)getSystemService( Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE));
...
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
        Process processSUkill9 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec( "su");
        DataOutputStream dataOutputStreamSUkill9 = new DataOutputStream( processSUkill9.getOutputStream());
        DataInputStream dataInputStreamSUkill9 = new DataInputStream(  processSUkill9.getInputStream());
     }
};
new Thread( runnable).start();
...
// and kill app
dataOutputStreamSUkill9.writeBytes( "kill -9 " + processInfo.pid + "\n");
dataOutputStreamSUkill9.flush();
// where processInfo is item from RunningAppProcessInfo
// example
// for( RunningAppProcessInfo processInfo : activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses())
// if( processInfo.processName.compareTo( "package.for.close") == 0)
```

Also you can try stop app by:

```
Method forceStopPackage = activityManager.getClass().getDeclaredMethod( "forceStopPackage", String.class);
forceStopPackage.setAccessible( true);
forceStopPackage.invoke( activityManager, "package.for.close");
```

Comment: Does the second method need Root access?

Comment: No, this is not require root, but may not work in last android version